# wxColourPickerCtrl tdm-1 gcc

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, tdm-gcc

After upgrading from 32 bit MinGW 4.8 to 32 bit TDM-1 GCC 5.1.0, wxColourPickerCtrl causes my program to crash regardless of whether I change color or not or click OK or cancel after the ColorPickerCtrl dialog shows. I am using wxWidgets-3.0.2 (monolithic, shared) on Windows 10. I was wondering if this could be a bug.

The constructor creating the dialog that has the control (some parts are omitted):

```
this->SetSizeHints( wxDefaultSize, wxDefaultSize );
Create(parent, wxID_ANY, wxT("Data Series List"), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize( 464,308 ), wxDEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE);
m_colorPicker = new wxColourPickerCtrl( this, wxID_ANY, *wxBLACK, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxCLRP_DEFAULT_STYLE );
fgSizer1->Add( m_colorPicker, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND, 5 );
m_colorPicker->Connect( wxEVT_COMMAND_COLOURPICKER_CHANGED, wxColourPickerEventHandler( dlgDataList::OnColourChanged ), NULL, this );
```

Event handling:

```
void dlgDataList::OnColourChanged( wxColourPickerEvent& event )
{
    m_DataListHasChanged=true;
    //event.Skip(); //Whether skipped or not, still crashes
}
```

Comment: could you please build dialogs sample, run it and see whether it crashes as well?

Comment: Funny thing, it happens only in release version. Debug version works well.

Comment: Just upgraded to 3.1.0 and still having the same problem

Comment: and you did reproduce it with the sample?

Comment: Yes, the same error happens when I run the code from samples/widgets. It runs in Debug version with no problem, but when I run the release version, the program crashes.

Comment: Problem solved: Downgraded to TDM-GCC MinGW 4.8.1. I am using wxWidgets 3.1.0 (monolithic, shared)

Comment: You could probably try upgrading to 5.3/5.4 especially if you need complete C++11 support.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, maybe a few months from now I will upgrade to 5.3 or 5.4.